# MemoryError: Unable to allocate 43.6 GiB for an array with shape (23162, 252377) and data type float64

Tags: keras, deep-learning, text-classification

I am getting the error `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 43.6 GiB for an array with shape (23162, 252377) and data type float64`. I am doing text classification using deep learning model:

```
import pandas
import tf
from tf.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

dataframe = pandas.read_excel('classes.xlsx')

dataframe.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)
data = dataframe
print(dataframe.head())

print(type(data['text']))


train_size = int(len(data) * .8)

print(int(len(data['text'])))
print(train_size)

texts = data['text']
tags = data['target']


train_posts = data['text'][:train_size]
train_tags = data['target'][:train_size]



test_posts = data['text'][train_size:]
test_tags =  data['target'][train_size:]

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=None,lower=False)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)

x_train = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(train_posts)
x_test = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(test_posts)
x_train = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(train_posts)
```

My dataset size is 24000 KB

The full stacktrace is:

```
  x_train = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(train_posts)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\text.py", line 383, in texts_to_matrix
    return self.sequences_to_matrix(sequences, mode=mode)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\text.py", line 413, in sequences_to_matrix
    x = np.zeros((len(sequences), num_words))
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 43.6 GiB for an array with shape (23162, 252377) and data type float64
```

Comment: Post the full stacktrace of your `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 43.6 GiB` so we can see what lines and syntax trigger it.

Comment: Also, what is the value of `train_size`?

Comment: @smci MemoryError: Unable to allocate 43.6 GiB for an array with shape (23162, 252377) and data type float64

Comment: **Post the full stacktrace** (in your question, not as a comment). The whole thing, not one line. That means all the lines of code in the stacktrace. We need to see which statement in which line is causing it.

Comment: the value of train size is 23162

Comment: @smci x_train = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(train_posts)

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\text.py", line 383, in texts_to_matrix
    return self.sequences_to_matrix(sequences, mode=mode)

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\text.py", line 413, in sequences_to_matrix
    x = np.zeros((len(sequences), num_words))

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 43.6 GiB for an array with shape (23162, 252377) and data type float64

Comment: Ok, post the full stacktrace in your question, not as a comment. So the offending function is `tokenizer.texts_to_matrix()`. You also need to add the missing import statements, presumably `tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer`. In your question, not as a comment. Next, check the doc on why `tokenizer.texts_to_matrix()` is mistakenyl thinking you're trying to allocate all that memory.

Comment: I edited the formatting of your stacktrace in the question. One line with 501 characters isn't readable... ;-)

Comment: You still also need to **add the missing import statements**, presumably `from tf.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer`

Comment: @smci I insert the num_words = 11000, the problem is IndexError: index 17159 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 11000

Answer (score 0):

So your call to [`tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer.texts_to_matrix()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer) is mistakenly trying to allocate a huge matrix. (You didn't add the missing import statements, but that's probably where your Tokenizer is coming from.)

Just from the doc page, set a limit on the number of words `num_words`, and thus on the output matrix size. Try `Tokenizer(..., num_words=20000)`. If that doesn't work, read the docpage and **reduce the arguments and input size** (e.g. only pass in first 10 lines of your training set [:10]) **until you get the matrix size down**. e.g. `num_words= 100`, or `num_words= 10` or even `num_words= 3`. Since it's obviously objecting to the size of your input.

Comment: when I tried to insert num_words = 20000. now the problem is 
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 3.45 GiB for an array with shape (23162, 20000) and data type float64. what i mean is it reduced the memory error from 43 GB to 3.4 GB but still not solved

Comment: Then try `num_words= 100`, or `num_words= 10` or `num_words= 3`, exactly like I suggested you 3 hours ago! **"reduce the arguments until you get the matrix size down"**

Comment: actually I tried that as you said to get the matrix down, but no the error is :IndexError: index 17159 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 11000

Comment: So you fixed the memory overallocation; that's just an indexing error of yours. Then figure out why your `train_posts = data['text'][:train_size]` is going wrong.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood; we're talking about the `Tokenizer(..., num_words=20000)` parameter. Nothing whatsoever to do with indexing your data with `[:train_size]`. Again, post your code (edit it into the question, not a comment).

Comment: ok, the problem is solved.. I really appreciate your help, thanks alot. @smci

Comment: How can I increase my testing accuracy? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66816865/mlp-keras-my-training-result-is-97-while-testing-is-86-can-i-increase-testing?noredirect=1#comment118111505_66816865 here is my question